# ASP.NET Parse URL Info

Tags: asp.net, regex, parsing, url, lambda

Aside from writing custom code are there any existing features in .NET which allows me to parse information from part of a URL? So my input will be like the below:

```
\Shop-Pet\Dog\Large\Africa-Lionhound\27-80?color-Dark
```

Is there a any easy way instead of using string split and/or regex afterwards to extract information into an array like the below:

```
[shop,pet]
[PetType, Dog]
[BreedSize, Large]
[Country, Africa]
[OtherNames, Lionhound]
[Height, 27]
[Weight, 80]
```

Thanks

Comment: pity my app is asp.net webform :(

Comment: they can be combined, but I'm guessing that's not a route you're able to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While not exactly what you need, `Request.Url.Segments` will return a string array of the different segments available to you. Given your example: 
/Shop-Pet/Dog/Large/Africa-Lionhound/27-80?color-Dark

it would return something to you like

```
{string[6]}
    [0]: "/"
    [1]: "Shop-Pet/"
    [2]: "Dog/"
    [3]: "Large/"
    [4]: "Africa-Lionhound/"
    [5]: "27-80"
```

You would have to handle the QueryString separately.

I don't think there's anything specifically like what you want, but Routes which are available in ASP.NET 4.0 could probably be setup to handle things exactly like you wanted.

Comment: thanks reconfirmed what I have though. String split might actually be better cleaner.